# How to access body from producertemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

The situation is as follows:

When a post request to a spring boot rout '/tweet' is called with a tweet as body, a route is started:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/tweet", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void storeTweet(@RequestBody TwitterBean twitterBean) {
    System.out.println("camel: " + twitterBean.getText());
    producerTemplate.sendBody("direct:storeTweet", twitterBean);
}
```

This works and I can access the body in a log in my route :

```
@Component
public class CamelRoutes extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("direct:firstRoute")
                .log("Camel body: ${body}");

        from("direct:storeTweet")
                .log("Store tweet: $(body)");
    }
}
```

What I really want to do though, is sending that body through to an other API like i did in this code snippet:

```
public void executePostWithCamel(TwitterBean tweet) throws Exception {
        try {
            camelContext.addRoutes(new RoutesBuilder() {
                @Override
                public void configure() {
                    from("timer://runOnce?repeatCount=1")
                            .id("tweetToDB")
                            .process(exchange -> exchange.getIn().setBody(tweet))
                            .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
                            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
                            .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
                            .to("http4://localhost:8085/twitterAPI/tweet")
                            .process(exchange -> log.info("The response code is: {}", exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE)));
                }
            });
            camelContext.start();
        } finally {
            //camelContext.stop();
        }
    }
```

However I cannot seem to figure out how to gain access to my tweet this time.

**EDIT:**

I've solved my problem with the following route:

```
from("direct:storeTweet")
                .process(exchange -> exchange.getIn().setBody(exchange.getIn().getBody()))
                .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
                .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
                .to("http4://ptsv2.com/t/5f02k-1519979843/post")
                .log("Store tweet: ${body}");
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean that you are trying to call the REST endpoint through camel ? In this statement `.process(exchange -> exchange.getIn().setBody(tweet))` what is tweet? where is it initialized? And lastly, when you execute this what is happening? Is your TwitterBean object in controller null?

Comment: Yes that's what I want to do. The tweet is passed as a method parameter in the working example. In my new example, it is passed as a json object in the body of a post request.

Comment: In this statement `.process(exchange -> exchange.getIn().setBody(tweet))` what is tweet? where is it initialized? And lastly, when you execute this what is happening? Is your TwitterBean object in controller null?

Comment: tweet is a POJO and it has been initialized. It's filled with relevant twitterdata. When I execute this, a post to "localhost:8085/twitterAPI/tweet " executed with the POJO as body.

Comment: Are you getting the pojo in your controller properly or u r getting it as null? In your route `from("direct:storeTweet")
                .log("Store tweet: $(body)");` It should be `${body}` not `$(body)`

Comment: Ah I see, yeah it was just a quick example I wrote. The tweet definitely is'nt zero in my controller. This I tested with : "System.out.println("camel: " + twitterBean.getText());"

Comment: I've managed to solve my problem, thank you anyway!

Comment: Use the requestXXX methods on ProducerTemplate to have the response. The send is for InOnly style, and request is for InOut style.